# Create main.tf resources only when a variable is set to true in the vars.tf file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I usually have one generic **main.tf** file that is the basis for all deployments to our environments (**DEV/STAGING/LIVE**). I have one parameter.tf file for each of those environments.

There is always a requirement to have some more expensive Azure options enabled in the STAGING and LIVE environments over what DEV might have - in my example its enabling the Azure Defender for SQL and extended Auditing functions for Azure SQL servers (PaaS)

This is a portion of my main.tf file that is generic...

```
# Define SQL Server 
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                          = var.azsqlserver1name
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                       = var.azsqlserver1version
  administrator_login           = var.azsqlserver1sauser
  administrator_login_password  = random_password.sql-password.result
  public_network_access_enabled = "true" # set to false with vNet integration
}

# Define Storage Account and container for SQL Threat Detection Policy Audit Logs 
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = var.azsaname1
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = var.azsatier1
  account_replication_type = var.azsasku1
  access_tier              = var.azsaaccesstier1
  account_kind             = var.azsakind1
  enable_https_traffic_only  = "true"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "vascans"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

# Defines Azure SQL Defender and Auditing - NOTE: Auditing - only SA out at the moment (11/2020) - Log Analytics and Event Hub in preview only
resource "azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy" "example" {
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  server_name                = azurerm_mssql_server.example.name
  state                      = var.azsqltreatdetectionstate
  storage_endpoint           = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_blob_endpoint
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  email_account_admins       = var.azsqltreatdetectionemailadmins
  retention_days             = var.azsqltreatdetectionretention
}
resource "azurerm_mssql_server_vulnerability_assessment" "example" {
  server_security_alert_policy_id = azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy.example.id
  storage_container_path          = "${azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.example.name}/"
  storage_account_access_key      = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  recurring_scans {
    enabled                   = var.azsqlvscansrecurring
    email_subscription_admins = var.azsqlvscansemailadmins
  }
}
resource "azurerm_mssql_server_extended_auditing_policy" "example" {
  server_id                               = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  storage_endpoint                        = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_blob_endpoint
  storage_account_access_key              = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  storage_account_access_key_is_secondary = false
  retention_in_days                       = var.azsqlauditretentiondays
}
```

What I need to do is have anything after the first **"azurerm_mssql_server"** resource to only be created in STAGING and LIVE (not DEV). I was planning to have a variable in the DEV/STAGING/LIVE parm tf files that state something like...

**DEVparm.tf**

```
variable azsqlenableazuredefenderforsql {
  default="false"
}
```

**STAGINGparm.tf and LIVEparm.tf**

```
variable azsqlenableazuredefenderforsql {
  default="true"
}
```

If this possible to achieve? Thus far I've draw a blank and tested a few things, but they don't quite work. It seems a simple enough vision, but when there is no IF... statement

Answer (score 1):

If you need to flip a resource on and off that is easy to achieve with count = 1 or 0.  This is usually handled with the ternary operator.

```
resource "some_resource" "example" {
 count = terraform.workspace != "development" ? 1 : 0
}
```

The count parameter was added to modules for terraform 0.13.  If you have a bundle of resources it could be an alterative method to excluding certain resources from building.

Answer (score 1):

One way that a lot of people solve this is by combining the `count` parameter on resources with a ternary. For example, look at the section entitled "If-Statements with the count parameter" in https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9#478c.

Basically you can keep your `azsqlenableazuredefenderforsql` variable and then in your resources do something like:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  count                 = var.azsqlenableazuredefenderforsql ? 1 : 0
  name                  = "vascans"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying this out yesterday before posting up here. I didn't get that much joy out of it unfortunately - seems its an issue.https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25578 My main issue is that the SA is also implied elsewhere in the other parts of the code, and that involves a lot of placing of [1] after the resource label...e.g. example[1].